# reload tab controller item

Tags: cocoa, swift3, tabbar

is it possible to reload a tab controller item every time i pressed a button?

for example:

```
class TabController: NSTabViewController {

    @IBAction func showFirstTab(_ sender: NSButton) {
        self.selectedTabViewItemIndex = 1
    }

}
```

i would like to reload the view of tab item 1 every time i pressed the tab. i work with swift 3 for osx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below UITabView delegate method and reload your view each time the tab is pressed. It informs the tab view controller that the specified tab is about to be selected.

To differentiate between the tab items you can set the NSTabViewItem identifier.

```
func tabView(_ tabView: NSTabView, willSelect tabViewItem: NSTabViewItem?)
```

Comment: sry but this doesn't work. perhaps ein did something wrong. i should put your code into my nstabviewcontroller?